# Cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'byte[]'

Tags: c#, decode, barcode, zxing

I am trying to decode a barcode from an .bmp file. However, I am getting an error saying Cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'byte[]'.

The line that getting error is **var barcodeResult = barcodeReader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using ZXing;

namespace barcode
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create a barcode reader instance
        var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();

        // create an in memory bitmap
        var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Users\jeremy\Desktop\qrimage.bmp");

        // decode the barcode from the in memory bitmap
        var barcodeResult = barcodeReader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);

        // output results to console
        Console.WriteLine($"Decoded barcode text: {barcodeResult?.Text}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Barcode format: {barcodeResult?.BarcodeFormat}");
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use the .NET Framework variant of ZXing? Only this has support for System.Drawing.Bitmap

Comment: Nope. How to find that?

Comment: Did you use the binaries from https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/releases or the nuget package? In the latter case: which target did you select in your project (.NET Framework, .NET Core, ...)?

Comment: yes I installed the ZXing package and i used .NET Framework

Comment: I just tested with a .NET Framework 4.7.2 Windows Forms app and the ZXing.Net v0.16.5 nuget package and it works fine.

Comment: Yes it works fine now. I used windows console. Thats y it didnt work. Thanks